# Does creating a File object create a physical file or touch anything outside the JVM?

Tags: java, file, jvm

Java class File has 4 constructors:

- `File(File parent, String child)`
        Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and 
  a child pathname  string.
- `File(String pathname)`
        Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string 
  into an    abstract pathname.
- `File(String parent, String child)`
        Creates a new File instance from a parent pathname string and a 
  child pathname string.
- `File(URI uri)`
        Creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into 
  an abstract pathname.

When I do:

```
File f=new File("myfile.txt");
```

Does a physical file on disk get created? Or does JVM make call to OS or does this only create an object inside JVM?

Comment: Consider the code new File("myfile.txt").exists(). Could this line return false, if a physical file is created when you do new File?

Comment: hakon - Sure it could - if someone between new File() and exists() deleted the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, creating a new `File` object does *not* create a file on the file system. In particular, you can create `File` objects which refer to paths (and even drives on Windows) which don't exist.

The constructors *do* ask the underlying file system representation to perform some sort of normalization operations if possible, but this *doesn't* require the file to be present. As an example of the normalization, consider this code running on Windows:

```
File f = new File("c:\\a/b\\c/d.txt");
System.out.println(f);
```

This prints

```
c:\a\b\c\d.txt
```

showing that the forward slashes have been normalized to backslashes - but the a, b, and c directories don't actually exist. I *believe* the normalization is more to do with the operating system naming scheme rather than any actual resources - I don't believe it even looks on disk to see if the file exists.

Comment: also when I call getName() doesn't touch any outside JVM?

Comment: @user710818: for this you can check the source (your JDK comes with a `src.zip` which contains the source of most Java classes). In this case: no, it's a getter that does some `String` manipulation, but no native method access (i.e. no calls outside the JVM).

Comment: @user710818...No, getName() too does not touch the file system. It just returns the name as a String. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29